# PHP code throws error if not inside a function

Tags: php, prestashop

First of all I'm really 'new' with PHP.

I'm modifying a prestashop module Minic MailChimp, and after developing a few functions I've tried to 'call' them via AJAX.

This is how I interact with PHP functions...

```
$('#btn_exec_new_list').on('click', function(){
    id_field = $('#id_field').val();
    name_field = $('#name_field').val();
    list_type = $('#list_type option:selected').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "minicmailchimp.php", 
        data: {id_field : id_field, name_field : name_field, list_type : list_type, add_list : '1'}, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
    }});
});
```

This is in the PHP side, considering this is all inside a CLASS (MinicMailchimp)

```
public function addList(){
    $settings = array();

    if(!empty($_POST['id_field']) || !empty($_POST['name_field']) || $_POST['list_type'] == 0){
        $this->message = array('text' => $this->l('Fill all the fields.'), 'type' => 'error');
        return;
    }

    $settings = array(
        'list_number' => $_POST['list_sendy']+1,
        'id_field'    => $_POST['id_field'],
        'name_field'  => $_POST['name_field'],
        'list_type'   => $_POST['list_type']
    );

    $list_name = "MINIC_MAILCHIMP_LIST".$settings['list_number'];
    Configuration::updateValue($list_name, serialize($settings));
}
```

And this is how I've seen I have to call it (This is also included in the same class as the function above). The thing is that any code I write outside a function throws syntax error.

```
if(isset($_POST['add_list'])){
    addList();
    $this->addList(); // Not sure which one use (I think it might be this one)
}
```

**Error:**

> [PrestaShop] Fatal error in module minicmailchimp:
>   syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

I have also tried to make it into a function and call it outside the class, but then it just simply doesn't work, tried to throw and echo and print it via AJAX but no answer at all. It doesn't even make it to the success part in AJAX.

```
class MinicMailchimp extends Module{
    public function executeFunction(){
        if(isset($_POST['add_list'])){
            echo "response from php";
            addList();
        } 
    }
}
call_user_func("executeFunction");
```

I've come to the conclusion that I don't know enough about classes and I can't just write php code outside a function. But it might be another thing.

Thank you and hopefuly this is enough information, keep in mind that is my first post.

Comment: It would be useful to add the error description. A class can hold only definitions (of properties and functions), you cannot have executable code that is inside the class but outside a function. But you can run it from outside the class defintion.

Comment: You'll need to learn something about OOP. `$this` refers to the current object instance and makes no sense outside of a `class`. Not sure what answer we can give here, certainly we can't teach you OOP from scratch.

Comment: Where does the called function resides ? Also inside the class? You should also edit your question and include the error.

Comment: @frz3993 - All PHP code resides inside the same class. Also included the error.

Comment: @syck - I also tried runing it outside the class definition, I included the code, please check if it is correct.

Comment: I never worked with prestashop but I'm guessing it could have something with how things work in it. For example, in wordpress you have to use admin-ajax.php to have proper ajax call. When I first tried to write my own ajax.php script for it, it refused it (I'm guessing do to security reasons they made it this way). It could be something similar there. Anyway, I know this isn't too helpful, but I want to recommend http://www.phptherightway.com/ and Modern PHP book, it's a good read for you to clarify some things. Also, check out this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Just as I thought. Basically, a class can have methods/functions and property declarations. Methods encapsulate the codes. You can't have codes outside a function. A class is a some kind of definition. You can create an object with that definition by calling `new`. It's like a `class Car{}` defines what a car should look like, and calling `new Car;` creates the Car.

Comment: Instead of using call_user_func() you would create an object and run the function on that. Read the documentation @BozidarSikanjic provided, and these things will soon become clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an ajax controller, and call it via ajax. The ajax controller will just channel requests to module's file. Create a file /minicmailchimp/controllers/front/ajax.php . The contents would be something like this:

```
class MinicMailchimpAjaxModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        if (Tools::getIsset('ajax')) {
            die($this->module->ajaxCall());
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your minicmailchimp.php file create a method "ajaxCall", and do:

```
public function ajaxCall()
{
    if (Tools::getIsset('add_list')) {
        // Whatever you need to do...
    }
}
```

And then call

```
$.ajax({url: pathToAjaxController, ...})
```

Remember to pass "ajax" in your ajax request, so, data: {ajax: true, ...}